# Search Method creates a binary operator error

Tags: java, search, binary, compareto, linear-search

I'm currently writing a method that will search through an already sorted array more efficiently than a simple linear search. The Idea is that the user will input a "Target" value they are locating, and the array will move up or down the array depending on the value until the midpoint (mid) finds it. However, when I try to compare the mid value with the target to detirmine if "target" is less or greater than "mid", I keep recieving a Bad Operand error for my less than and greater than values because I am comparing target to an int, when I'm really trying to gather whether the value of "mid" compared to target is greater than 0 or less than 0. So "mid" can detirmine whether to move up or down the array. Any ideas on how to solve this for the method? (Sorry if I am making this confusing, It's been a long night)

```
 for (int x=0; x<array.length; x++)
 {
    int min = 0, mid, max=array.length-1;

    do
    {
    mid = (min + max) / 2;
       if(array[mid].compareTo(target < 0))
       {
          max = mid - 1;   //moves down the array
       }
       else if(array[mid].compareTo(target > 0))
       {
          min = mid + 1;   //moves up the array 
       }
       else
       {
          return mid;
       }
   }
   while(min<=max);
   {
      return -1; //after dropping out of the while loop
   }
}
```

}

ERROR: SearchUtils.java:28: error: bad operand types for binary operator '<'
    if(array[mid].compareTo((target) <0))
                                            ^
  first type:  Comparable
  second type: int
SearchUtils.java:32: error: bad operand types for binary operator '>'
   else if(array[mid].compareTo(target >0))
                                               ^
  first type:  Comparable
  second type: int
2 errors

Comment: if(array[mid].compareTo(target < 0)) this should be if(array[mid].compareTo(target)<0)

Answer (score 0):

Take the predicate out of the function call:

```
if(array[mid].compareTo(target) < 0)
```